# Validate Input fields only on submit angularjs

Tags: angularjs, validation

I am trying to show a Validation Summary, a Div on top of the page with all the Validation error messages in angularjs, on form submit.
I am using the below logic to show/ hide the top div with validation messages,

```
<div class="alert alert-error" ng-show="submitted && myForm.$invalid">
</div>
```

I am setting the variable submitted to true on save button click. It's working Okay the first time, but after the first submission, if enter the value for the input field(required field) and clear it, it's kicking off the validation(the top div shows).

Is there a way to show the validation div, only on the submit of the form and not when the user clears the input field ?

***UPDATE***

```
$scope.save = function (myForm) {

    $scope.submitted = true;

    if (myForm.$invalid) {
        return;
    }

    $scope.submitted = false;
}
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm one way to do it would be to watch the [FormController](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController)'s property `$dirty` and `$setPristine()` method, and use a variable `hasError` to show the error or not.

[See this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KNM2CLre3HIgHaQq7o3i?p=preview) as an example

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
controller('AppController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.hasError = false;

  $scope.$watch('theForm.$dirty', function() {
    $scope.hasError = false;
    $scope.theForm.$setPristine();
  });

  $scope.save = function() {
    $scope.hasError = $scope.theForm.$invalid;

    if($scope.hasError) {
      // perform error routine
    } else {
     // perform save routine
    }
  };

}]);
```

**HTML**

```
   <body ng-controller="AppController">

    <div class="error" ng-show="hasError">This is an error</div>

    <form name="theForm" ng-submit="save()" novalidate>
      <input type="text" name="text1" ng-model="text1" required>
      <input type="text" name="text2" ng-model="text2" required>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are setting submitted to false upon display of your validation div else it'll show up after each additional validation call.

```
    $scope.save = function (myForm) {

        $scope.submitted = true;

            if (myForm.$invalid) {
                    $scope.submitted = false;
                    return;
            }
    }
```

Comment: I set $scope.submitted = false; inside the save method. Please see my update

Comment: Won't the return cause it to bounce out of the save function before it ever hits the line to set it to false? I'd place the $scope.submitted = false; within the conditional right above the return statement.

Comment: we cannot do that, the moment you set $scope.submitted = false; the  ng-show="submitted && myForm.$invalid" kicks in and hides the Div !

Comment: Doh! Rookie mistake. Right, so what you want to do is set $scope.submitted = false; within the dismissal of your div. That way, once the user excuses the dialogue they won't bounce it back up until they submit the form again.